# Passing property to PHP method

Tags: php, oop, methods, properties

I have the following class, where I added the property `$user`.

```
  include_once(__CA_LIB_DIR__."/ca/Search/BaseSearch.php");
    include_once(__CA_LIB_DIR__."/ca/Search/ObjectSearchResult.php");

class ObjectSearch extends BaseSearch {
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Which table does this class represent?
         */
        protected $ops_tablename = "ca_objects";
        protected $ops_primary_key = "object_id";
        public $user;
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        public function &search($ps_search, $pa_options=null, $user) {
                return parent::doSearch($ps_search, new ObjectSearchResult(), $pa_options);
        }
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
}
?>
```

In the following code I can't pass the `$user` property to the search method. I tried with `$user`, `$this->user` and `new ObjectSearch($user)`. Being new to PHP I know I'm asking a naive question, but I can't solve it by myself, believe me I tried for days. How can I accomplish this?

```
$po_request                     = $this->getVar('request');
$vs_widget_id                   = $this->getVar('widget_id');
$user                           = $this->getVar('user');

$o_search = new ObjectSearch();
$result = $o_search->search('created.$user.:"2013"');

$count = 1;
while($result->nextHit()) {
print "Hit ".$count.": "."<br/>\n";
print "Idno: ".$result->get('ca_objects.idno')."<br/>\n";
print "Name: ".$result->get('ca_objects.preferred_labels.name')."<br/>\n";
$count++;

}


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function &search($ps_search, $pa_options=null, $user)
```

There are a few things wrong with it:

1. It doesn't make any sense to pass a parameter without default value after a parameter which has a default value
2. You have to pass the third parameter here (you only pass one)
3. You don't have to pass the class properties manually; they're automatically in `$this`

So write:

```
    public function &search($ps_search, $pa_options=null) {
            return parent::doSearch($ps_search, new ObjectSearchResult($this->user), $pa_options);
    }
```

Or where ever you may need your `$user` class property, write simply `$this->user`.

`$this` is always set in object context: you don't need to pass it yourself.

Comment: Hi! I edited the code as you kindly sugested, but still isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, this whas the other part of my answer.    $result = $o_search->search('created' .$this->user. ':"2012"');// In this line if I replace $this->user with a string the code works fine. Can't figure out why.                                                     This is how I edited the class:                                               public $user = sscarano;
        public function &search($ps_search, $pa_options=null) {
        return parent::doSearch($ps_search, new   ObjectSearchResult($this->user), $pa_options);
        }

Comment: Ah, ___there___... Then use `$o_search->user`.

Comment: $o_search -> user = sscarano;
echo  $o_search -> user; //This prints sscarano. But this line of code     $result = $o_search->search('created.$this->user.:"2012"');// acts as if I typed ('created..:"2012"') It ignores $this->user. If i replace $this->user for sscarano it works fine.

Comment: `$result = $o_search->search('created.'.$o_search->user.'.:"2012"');` is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse double quotes with single ones. You have to either use concatenation or double ones here:

```
$result = $o_search->search('created ' . $user . ': 2013');
```

or

```
$result = $o_search->search("created $user: 2013");
```